# Python - Loop através de intervalo de datas

Tags: python, loop, while

Bom dia,

Sou relativamente novo em Python, e, preciso de uma luz para um loop com datas.
Trata-se de um projeto com Selenium, preciso fazer buscas em determinado site através de um intervalo de datas.

O resultado dessa busca trará informações limitadas à 5000 registros.
Então basicamente, eu havia pensado em atribuir data inicial e final à duas variáveis e conforme fosse encontrando o valor de registro igual a 5000, fosse subtraindo 3 dias da data final, até que chegasse em um intervalo de datas em que o resultado fosse inferior a 5000.

Até essa etapa, ok. Porém meu problema é como retornar a busca para os dias em que foram subtraídos anteriormente, necessitando um novo loop por eles.
Por exemplo, digamos que minha data inicial e final seja 01/07/2022 e 31/07/2022 respectivamente, e que o primeiro intervalo com a quantidade de registros buscados seja 01/07/2022 a 07/07/2022. Minha dificuldade está em como continuar o loop entre 08/07/2022 a 31/07/2022 onde existe a possibilidade de novamente ter que subtrair de 3 em 3 dias a data final.
Abaixo o código

```
#Criando uma lista com as datas
data_inicial = '01/07/2022'
data_final = '31/07/2022'


dRan = pd.date_range(start = datetime.strptime(data_inicial, '%d/%m/%Y').date(), 

       end =datetime.strptime(data_final, '%d/%m/%Y').date(), periods = 31)   

res = dRan.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

Datas = []
for i in res:
    Datas.append(i)

tamanho_periodo = len(Datas)-1
novo_tamanho_periodo = tamanho_periodo
print(f'data inicial é {Datas[0]} e a data_final é {Datas[tamanho_periodo]}')


Registros = 27000

ind = 0


while Registros >= 5000:
    
    #Subtrai 3 dias do valor da data final
    novo_tamanho_periodo = novo_tamanho_periodo - 3
    
    nova_data_final = Datas[novo_tamanho_periodo]
    #Simulando nova consulta
    Registros -= 3000
    ind += 3
    print(f'data inicial é {Datas[0]} e a data_final é {nova_data_final}')
    
print(f'data inicial é {Datas[tamanho_periodo - ind + 1]} e a data_final é {data_final}')
```

O meu retorno nesse exemplo:

```
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 31/07/2022, número total de registros são 27000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 28/07/2022, número total de registros são 24000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 25/07/2022, número total de registros são 21000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 22/07/2022, número total de registros são 18000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 19/07/2022, número total de registros são 15000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 16/07/2022, número total de registros são 12000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 13/07/2022, número total de registros são 9000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 10/07/2022, número total de registros são 6000
data inicial é 01/07/2022 e a data_final é 07/07/2022, número total de registros são 3000

data inicial é 08/07/2022 e a data_final é 31/07/2022, número total de registros são 20000
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, dizer se há como fazer esse loop sem que precise adicionar um While pra cada vez que os registros cheguem a 5000. Acredito que deva ter alguma forma mais inteligente de fazer isso, mas não consegui pensar no momento rsrsrs

É meu primeiro post aqui, caso não tenha ficado no padrão, adequarei.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Isso me parece um caso de loop dentro de loop. O loop mais externo checaria se a data inicial é igual a data final, a cada vez q executá-lo, vc atualiza a data inicial pra ser `Datas[tamanho_periodo - ind + 1]`. Dentro desse loop teria o bloco de while que você escreveu. Creio que o caminho pra solução esteja aí (não tô dando a solução de bandeja pq vc parece estar aprendendo)

Um caminho interessante seria usar [flags](https://techterms.com/definition/flag#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20flag,store%20a%20range%20of%20values.) pra checar se é um determinado caso